# Currently Using CodeIgniter Framework i have an Error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$U_Model
>
> Filename: controllers/Login.php
>
> Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cmsproject\application\controllers\Login.php
>
> Line: 24
>
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cmsproject\index.php
>
> Line: 315
>
> Function: require_once
>
> **$data=$this->U_Model->loginf($loginf['username'], $loginf['password']);**
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function loginf() on null
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cmsproject\application\controllers\Login.php
>
> Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cmsproject\index.php
>
> Line: 315
>
> Function: require_once

Model File Is Here:

```
<?php
class U_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function loginf($username,$pass){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$pass);
        if($query=$this->db->get()){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: model name should not be recommended like this in CI, by the way ,have you loaded your model in controller

Comment: yes i load model in controller

Comment: make sure model class name should match with the name of the model file name

Comment: yes it is same file name and class name

Comment: $data=$this->U_Model->loginf($loginf['username'], $loginf['password']);

Comment: on line 24 this a piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your controller should be like this :

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('User');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('U_Model');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

    /*added public before loginp*/

    public function loginp(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        /*md5 not recommended*/

        $data = $this->U_Model->loginf($username, $password);

        if( ! empty($data))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('sid',$data['id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('sname',$data['name']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$data['username']);
            redirect('login/home');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('emsg','Please Enter Your Correct Name And Password');
            redirect('login/home');
        }
    }

    public function home(){
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}?>
```

Change your model like this

```
<?php
class U_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function loginf($username,$pass)
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$pass);
        $query = $this->db->get('users')
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: show your controller how you passing parameters to model method

Comment: see my updated answer add public with loginp method, and many changes are there

Comment: change your controller and model according to my answer>are you still getting the error,

Comment: happy to hear its help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class U_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function loginf($username,$pass)
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$pass);
        $query = $this->db->get('users')
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('User');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('U_Model');
    }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to use the correct [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for PHP or HTML to appear correctly in your answer. Also, you should [edit] your answer to add additional information, not post it as a comment where it is unreadable. Finally, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.